# PHP property decleration accepts array and do not accept any of other expressions that could be evaluated at the compilation process

Tags: php, oop, properties

while studying oop in PHP, I noticed that the property declaration accepts an array as value as mentioned here [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

```
class Test{
      public $var7 = array(true, false);
}
```

and I noticed that the documentation says  :

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

and after reading **[this](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-php-executes-from-source-code-to-render/)** article to know how the compilation process works, I realized that within the compilation process, some expressions would be evaluated and optimized if it possible like the below snippet :

```
var x = strlen ("testing") => int(7);
```

if using the array as a value in declaring property worked because it's evaluated in the compilation process, then why did not the below initialization work if logically both of them could be evaluated at the compilation process and this is the condition to initialize a property in a class?

```
     Class Test {
          public $vars=strlen("random"); // Fails
     }
```

Comment: What if there's another `strlen` function defined in a namespace?

Comment: @u_mulder : Could you please clarify as i'm beginner in OOP.

Comment: Sometimes calls internal function can be optimized during compilation, and they will be, but not always. That's why declarations only accept constant values. The manual should probably read 'for example' or 'at least' instead of 'that is'. But I don't know how many people infer that anything that can be analysed/optimized is valid syntax for declarations.

Comment: @jh1711  & u_mulder : Both of you are right. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that `strlen()` is a function while `array()` is a [keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

The critical difference to understand is that keywords always reference the same thing regardless of context.

From php.net:

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names.

Functions, on the other hand, could be defined differently depending on where you are calling them.

Consider this simplistic example:
First a file we'll call "functions.php".

```
//functions.php
namespace My_Project_Namespace;

function strlen($string){
    return 10;  //In my project, all strings are length 10! 10 is a nice round number...
}
```

In this file, I am overriding the built-in `strlen()` function with another one. This is possible because my function is defined inside a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) (in this case, `My_Project_Namespace`).

Now consider your file, but this time let's put it in our namespace (you should be name-spacing all your functions and classes)

```
//Test.php
namespace My_Project_Namespace;

Class Test {
    public $vars=strlen("random"); // Fails
}
```

`strlen()` has 2 definitions depending on the namespace.  Since knowing the current namespace depends on runtime information the compiler cannot know which to use for initialization in the class.  Even if you didn't define a custom `strlen()` function you still couldn't do this because knowing that there isn't another version `strlen()` also depends on runtime information!

`array()` is a totally different beast.  It is a keyword, you cannot define another meaning for `array()` so the compiler doesn't have to worry about one existing.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clear message, you answered all my thoughts, thanks for your time.